# Laravel default auth for login generating unexpected error

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel's (6.2) default auth for user authentication. In my login form when I hit the default login route(**'login'**) provided by laravel it is showing me the **wrong credential provided** error though my credentials are correct. I used a seeder to generate my first user(default user for the site) and used the global `bcrypt()` (also tried `Hash::make()`) method to hash my password. I am using **'file'** session driver which comes default too.

The most interesting part is that when I fire the `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` command or `php artisan migrate` following by `php artisan db:seed` command, the auth works fine for the first time, That means when I try to log in immediately after firing those command the auth works fine till logout. But after that, when I do log out manually or session turns invalid, I can't login even though my credentials are correct. Any solution for that?

For seeder reference here what I applied to make the default user

```
\App\User::create([
    'name'     => "John Doe",
    'email'    => 'john@example.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('password')
]);
```

Comment: Try to upload your code, like factory you are creating etc.

Comment: check your database after logout if any changes occurs in user table

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I used everything comes with default auth, didn't modify any controller or traits for login, that's why didn't upload the code.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan no changes in the database, as I am maintaining 'file' session driver so no changes on the database. Not even in the users table

Answer (score -2):

Do you check as `Hash::check(normal_password,hashed_password);` in login function?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I let laravel to handle the login with it's default authentication. So yes, behind the scene laravel is checking the plain password and the hashed password

Comment: Please don't use answers for further questions. You can use comments for getting more information.